# hadoop streaming: how to see application logs?

Tags: python, logging, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I can see all hadoop logs on my `/usr/local/hadoop/logs` path

but where can I see application level logs? for example :

mapper.py

```
import logging

def main():
    logging.info("starting map task now")
    // -- do some task -- //
    print statement
```

reducer.py

```
import logging
def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        logging.info("received input to reducer - " + line)  
        // -- do some task -- //
        print statement
```

Where I can see `logging.info` or related log statements of my application?
I am using `Python` and using `hadoop-streaming`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop streaming uses [STDIN/STDOUT](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/streaming.html#How+Streaming+Works) for passing the key/value pairs between the mappers and reducers, so the log messages have to be written to a specific log file - check the [sample code](http://www.mechanicalcat.net/richard/log/Python/Simple_usage_of_Python_s_logging_module) and the [python logging documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/logging.html) for more details. This [Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825905/python-logging-info-not-logging-the-message) might also help.

Comment: Thank you Praveen, I added the logging.warn statements and it started to accumulate logs in /usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/<mapper|reducer>dir/stderr file

Comment: for the record (five years later...), the default logging level is `logging.WARNING`; to emit info-level statements in the code above, the root (default) logger's level must be changed: `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)`

Answer (score 5):

Hadoop gathers stderr, which can be viewed on hadoop map/reduce status site. So you can just write to stderr.

Comment: just write to stderr: `import sys; print >> sys.stderr, 'spam'` or other alternatives at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574702/how-to-print-to-stderr-in-python